# can i display just div in my ajax not all page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

can I display just div in my ajax not all page?
allpage was charged, but I want just to show one div and don't show the header and footer and don't remove it because I need the header

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://test_12.com/test_payed",
 // cache: false,
  success: function(html){
        $(".results").append(html);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Read about `preventDefault`.

Comment: Sincerly to me is not clear, "dont show the header and dont remove it because i need the header". Please can you be more clear and if possible with a simple example show what is your result, what is the result you expect and the code you try to get the expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead, which allows to load fragments of a resource

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

---

```
$(".results").load("https://test_12.com/test_payed #YourDiv");
```

---

> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `https://test_12.com/test_payed`,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of `YourDiv`. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the elements with a class of `results`, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after....

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://test_12.com/test_payed",
 // cache: false,
  success: function(html){
        $(".results").append($(html).find('#OnlyThisDiv'));
      }
  });
```